# Laravel & Dropzone file delete not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, dropzone.js

I want to delete files from server which have been uploaded through Dropzone.But,Only thumbnails have been deleted.File in the server not erased.I have got an error in console.http://localhost:8000/upload/delete 500 (Internal Server Error)'

My Upload Method In Controller

```
public function upload(Request $request){
           $file= $request->file('file');
           $filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
           $upload='uploads/topics';
           $file->move($upload, $filename);
    }
```

Dropzone Script file.

```
Dropzone.options.addImages = {
maxFilesize: 8,
addRemoveLinks: true,
dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',

init:function() {

        this.on("removedfile", function(file) {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'upload/delete',
                data: {id: file.name},
                dataType: 'html',
                 success: function(data){
                    var rep = JSON.parse(data);

                 }
            });

        } );
    },
}
```

My delete method in controller.

```
public function delete(Request $request){
         $filename = $request->input('id');
          unlink('uploads/topics'.$filename);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two issues that I can see right away:

1. In your `delete` controller method you are trying to access `$request` but you haven't injected it.
2. The request `input` method is lowercase.

I believe this is closer to what you need:

```
public function delete(Request $request){    
    $filename = $request->input('id');
    unlink('uploads/topics/' . $filename);
}
```

---

Some notes:

1. Whenever you get an "internal server error" that means you need to check your error logs. There are details in one of your log files that will tell you the exact error.
2. Right now your delete method could allow a user to delete things you may not want them to delete. I could easily post a filename to that endpoint and delete anything from your `topics` folder.
3. Even more dangerous, this code appears to be at risk for a traversal attack. See here for details: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal

Comment: I have updated the cod as per you say.But This is not working,How can i check log files?

Comment: You need to be more specific than just "not working." Your error logs depend on what webserver you're using. Maybe this will help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5127884/660694

Comment: You should also do some basic troubleshooting in your `delete` method. Do a `dd($request->all())` to make sure you're getting the id parameter. Do a `dd('uploads/topics/' . $filename);` before the unlink, to make sure the path looks good. This is just debugging 101 stuff here.

Comment: Look also in the `app/Http/routes.php` file. Is your delete route really `/upload/delete` or is it possible just `/delete`?

Comment: i do a dd($request->all()) as you say.I also do a dd('uploads/topics/' . $filename);But Nothing happened.I am getting the same error.I am using wamp  server.

Comment: That means your issue is somewhere else, in code that you haven't posted. Did you look at the routes file as I suggested? Also, you need to research where WAMP is putting your error log files. Do some searching on that, you absolutely need to know where the error logs are for the future.